# Hosts file map localhost to existing domain not subdirectory* updated

Tags: mac, localhost, hosts, mamp

I am locally developing a website via MAMP and rather than messing with the changing all of my links and etc later on I opened up `etc/hosts` and added this line `127.0.0.1    localhost mysite.com` so that my site thinks it has the `mysite.com` domain name, this works great. However I can't access a part of my site within a subdomain etc `sub.mysite.com` routes to `localhost`. Is there any way to route `localhost` to `mysite.com` yet still keep `sub.mysite.com` accessible?

UPDATE:
I just found out that my subdomain is redirecting to my domain. I'm gonna guess that it is virtually impossible to prevent localhost from routing to some specific directory ex. `mysite.com/example/`.

Comment: That shouldn't happen; something else is screwed up.

Comment: Your right, I just noticed that my subdomain is redirecting to my domain, please check the update to my post. Is there anything that can be done?

Comment: I'd say "probably not".  Why would you be redirecting between subdomains anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In windows, I think if "domain.com" is mapped to localhost, it is independent from sub.domain.com. You need to specify every single subdomain in the hosts file for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I just got done figuring out what the problem was. If you look into your `private/var/log/apache2/error_log` (or whatever your error log file may be) you'll notice that there's an error that says `VirtualHost overlap on port XXXX`.

To get away without overlapping (which will default to the first VirtualHost) specify a `NameVirtualHost` in your httpd.conf like this:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "/Users/Thomas/Sites/mysite"
  ServerName mysite.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "/Users/Thomas/Sites/subsite"
  ServerName sub.mysite.com
</VirtualHost>
```

You may have already figured out how to do this, but I had a difficult time trying to find the answer myself so I might as well make it easier to find for other people.